# Have you seen Google Calendar ICS subscriptions functioning as advertised? Refresh is slow

Tags: google-calendar

I've found that when subscribing my Google Calendar to an ICS feed, it takes hours, in some cases over 12 hours, for the updates to appear in Google Calendar.

They advertise that it self-refreshes every two minutes, but I've noticed this for over a year now.

Anyone else see this happening?

For clarification, I'm talking *not* about subscribing to my Google Calendar ICS feed, but rather using Google Calendar to subscribe to a different ICS feed.

Answer (score 3):

The google calendar help suggests that google calendar is expected to be updating at least once every 24 hours.  But I think you might find that google calendar normally checks for updates every six hours.

I've got some users picking up ical feeds generated from Moodle, and others using a perl script which does a bit of screen scraping from another app.  The moodle calendars change quite infrequently, but the perl calendars may change on an hourly basis.

Checking the logs on my server, I can see google calendar bot routinely fetching either type of ical feed every six hours for most of our users, regardless of the type of feed, or apparently the frequency of recent changes.

More discussion about this over here:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=7c6b4213a42e6923&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you trim old data and adjust the headers for the serving ical file, Google will speed up their refresh. Here's an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158546/78212